# unable to insert into table by mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

I wanna to create a trigger that insert the post id and meta_value to another table (subscription_lookup) after there is a new insertion to the wp_postmeta table. Anyone can tell me which part did I do wrong as the code is not working

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE  TRIGGER `wp_postmeta_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `wp_postmeta` 
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
SET @order_id = ( SELECT new.post_id FROM wp_postmeta
where meta_key = '_paid_date');

 SET @paid_date = ( SELECT new.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
where meta_key = '_paid_date' );

 INSERT INTO subscription_lookup (subscription_id, start_date)
  VALUES (@order_id,@paid_date);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `NEW.column_name` already stores the value for the row which is currently processed by trigger - you do not need in SELECT.

Comment: But without select I couldnt use the where statement

Comment: You cannot select `NEW.column`!!! `NEW` is NOT a table. Assume that `NEW.column` is a name of scalar local variable, and its prefix (`NEW.`) shows that it stores (already stores!) new value which is assigned (already assigned! the trigger is AFTER) to the column.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to SQL but thx again for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `wp_postmeta_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `wp_postmeta` 
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO subscription_lookup (subscription_id, start_date)
    SELECT NEW.post_id, NEW.meta_value
    WHERE NEW.meta_key = '_paid_date';
```

This trigger checks does the row inserted into `wp_postmeta` contains `'_paid_date'` property and if true then it inserts the values inserted into logging table else none is inserted.